# Installing Windows Components After SP1

Tags: iis, windows-7

I don't recall having to do it in Vista, but if I add a component to Windows 7 (e.g. IIS) do I need to reapply SP1?

Answer (score 2):

No.  SP1 should only need to be applied once.

**Update**

Starting with Vista, the architecture of Windows is different than that of XP.  All features/components are in the code base already, so when SP1 is applied to Windows 7, it updates that code base.  Turning on or turning off Windows features does not actually add/remove it from your hard disk.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-features-on-or-off

Comment: @Rob I'd like to mark this as the answer, but I would feel better about doing it if can you provide a reference to some statement from Microsoft.

Comment: I've added additional info which should clarify.